# Validation input on the length of the username and password numbers

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox

i would like to make an input on the length of the numbers of the username and password, when i try to enter a number greater than the allowed number and set in the condition it keeps giving me that the input is valid although i had exceeded the limit there numbers to enter, below i attach the code.

```
 private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) // button associated with all the numbers in the keypad I created 
    {
        if (txt_Username.Enabled == true)
        {
            txt_Username.Text += ((System.Windows.Forms.Button)sender).Text;


            if (txt_UserName.Text.Length > 9)
            {
                txt_Username.Enabled = true;
                label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label6.Text = "username must contain a maximum of 9 numbers";
                txt_nomeUtente.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                txt_Username.Enabled = true;
                label6.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                label6.Text = "username is acceptable";
                txt_Password.Focus();
            }








        }

        else if (txt_Password.Enabled == true)
        {
            txt_Password.Text += ((System.Windows.Forms.Button)sender).Text;

          

            if (txt_Password.Text.Length > 9)
            {
                txt_Password.Enabled = true;
                label7.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label7.Text = "Password must contain a maximum of 9 numbers";
                
                txt_nomeUtente.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                txt_Password.Enabled = true;
                label7.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                label7.Text = "The password is acceptable";
                txt_Password.Focus();
            }



        }
    }


private void button15_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) // Button ENTER of the keypad that I created 

    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_UserName.Text))
        {
            txt_UserName.Enabled = true;
            txt_Password.Enabled = false;
            label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label6.Text = "Username empty";
            txt_User.Focus();
            //txt_UserName = txt_Password;

        }
        else
        {
            txt_UserName.Enabled = true;
            txt_Password.Enabled = true;
            label6.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            label6.Text = "Username is acceptable";
            txt_Password.Focus();
            txt_UserName = txt_Password;
        
        }
        
         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_Password.Text))
        {
            txt_Password.Enabled = true;
            label7.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label7.Text = "Password is Empty";
            label6.Text = "";
          
            txt_Password.Focus();
            

        }
        else 
        {
            txt_Password.Enabled = true;
            txt_UserName.Enabled = true;
            label7.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            label7.Text = "Password is acceptable";
            txt_Password = txt_UserName;
           
            txt_UserName.Focus();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you aware of the [Error provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) supported by winforms?

Comment: yes, here however I inserted a label to notify me of an error, I did not choose to use an error provider